# Exclude files from "checkJS"

Tags: visual-studio-code, checkjs

Can I somehow exclude dedicated files from VSCodes setting `"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true`?

I'd like to not have my webpack builds checked which are all placed in a `dist` folder.

I know that I could add `**/dist/*` or `**/dist` to `files.exclude` but this would (by definition) hide them completely from the files explorer which is not what I want since I'd like to have the possibility to inspect them from time to time.

Here's how an example setup of mine looks like:

[image]

My `jsconfig.js` looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "checkJs": true
    },
    "include": [
        "**/src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

In my understanding it shouldn't check the files within `dist` in the first place...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized that this happened since I was enabling the `checkJs` twice:

- In `jsconfig.json`
- In the workspace settings via `"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true`

After removing `"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true` from the settings everything works as expected and only files within `src` folders are checked...